# Difference between Ramp-up time and Duration defined in scheduler configuration?

Tags: jmeter

Test Plan:

- Number of threads - 11
- Ramp-up period - 660
- Loop count - 3

(Every 60 second(660/11) 3 requests hits the server.)

- Duration - 180 seconds
- Start up delay - 120 Seconds

As defined in duration, Test execution will be completed in 3 minutes but it took 12 minutes to complete the test.

Also, there are 11 threads.So, every thread will hit the server after 60 seconds (11*60) i.e. it will took 11 minutes to complete the test.But it took 12 minutes to complete whole test.
I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

- **Duration** - how long your test is allowed to run (mostly used with "Forever" Loop Count to limit the test run time). In your current setup it is **not getting applied**.
- **Ramp-Up** - JMeter starts threads (virtual users) defined in Thread Group during the Ramp-Up period. So if you have 11 virtual users and 11 minutes ramp-up JMeter will start with 1 user and add another virtual user every minute. Once started each virtual user will start executing sampler(s) upside down, in your case each virtual user will execute each sampler
- **Startup delay**: there are 2 minutes where nothing is happening in the beginning of your test

So your test looks as follows:

1. 120 seconds nothing happens
2. Then 1st thread is being kicked off, it executes sampler(s) one time
3. Then nothing happens for another minute
4. 2nd thread executes sampler(s) one time
5. steps 2-3 repeat for each thread
6. On 12th minute when last thread executes last sample your test finishes.

Going forward I would recommend using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for setting desired requests per minute rate and [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides easy visual way of defining the load pattern.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. So,total execution time of the test is not dependent on Ramp up time.